# why does the named javascript function persist?

Tags: javascript, function, closures, function-expression

This is an adaptation of what you'd find in john resig's Learning Advanced Javascript app.

```
var math = {
    fact: function fact(n){
        return n > 0 ? n * fact(n-1): 1;
    },
    fact1: function (n) {
        return n > 0? n * math.fact1(n-1) : 1;
    }
};

console.log(math.fact(5));  // 120
console.log(math.fact1(5)); // 120

var o = {
    x: math.fact,
    y: math.fact1
};

math = {};

console.log(o.x === undefined); // false
console.log(o.y === undefined); // false
console.log(o.x(5));            // 120
console.log(o.y(5));            // Uncaught TypeError: math.fact1 is not a function
```

One would expect `o.x(5)` should throw an error, but it executes. Why?

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect an error...

Comment: `o.y(5)` throws an error...so shouldn't `o.x(5)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an object literal expression is evaluated, the expression to the right of each colon is evaluated and assigned to the specified property.

So when this executes:

```
var o = {
    x: math.fact,
    y: math.fact1
};
```

the expression `math.fact` is evaluated, and the result is the function that `math.fact` is referring to *at that time*.

The same goes for `math.fact1`.

So even if you reassign the `math` variable with `math = {}`. `o.x` will continue to refer to that function. The `o` object has no knowledge of the `math` variable.

---

The reason why `o.y(5)` throws an error has to do with closures.

`o.y` refers to this function:

```
function (n) {
     return n > 0? n * math.fact1(n-1) : 1;
}
```

You can see here that it uses the `math` *variable*. Even if you reassign the `math` variable, this function will continue to refer to the variable itself.

When you call `o.y(5)`, the function executes, but when it tries to call `math.fact(n-1)`, that fails, because `math` no longer has a property called `fact`.

---

`o.x` does not have the problem that `o.y` has. It is a named function, and therefore is able to continue to call itself even after `math` is reassigned.

Comment: This makes more sense...when I replaced `math.fact1` with `arguments.callee` it works. Now all makes sense...it never occurred to me that that was the cause of the error.

Comment: I think that `arguments.callee` is now deprecated, so be aware of that.

Comment: @deostroll I'm glad I was able to clear that up. Bear in mind that the use of `arguments.callee` is not recommended, and it is prohibited in ES5 strict mode. Using a named function like you are doing in `fact()` is the preferred approach.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you would expect an error on `o.x`.

At the start, when we define `math = { ... }`, we have two functions.

The first function is referenced *both* by its name `fact`, and by the object property `math.fact`

The second function is anonymous, and is referenced only by `math.fact1`

We then "copy" the functions into `o`. At this point, the first function is referenced by all of `fact`, `math.fact` and `o.x`, while the second function is referenced by `math.fact1` and `o.y`.

We then destroy the `math` object by replacing it with a new, empty object. At this point, the first function is referenced by `fact` and `o.x`, and the second only by `o.y`.

Now we actually call the functions. `o.x` contains a recursive call to `fact`, which is very clearly still defined as that function. However, `o.y` contains a recursive call to `math.fact1`, which we destroyed, hence an error there.

This has nothing to do with... well, anything of interest. The function that names something that still exists continues to work, while the function that names something that doesn't exist any more fails.

I mean... duh...

Comment: This answer is more descriptive, and well explained

Answer (score 1):

`o.x` is a reference to a function (object). Because of this reference, the fact function will keep existing after the math object has been reset (objects only get garbage collected when no reference to them exist anymore).